# Trouble performing calculations from loaded TXT file using C++ loop

Tags: c++, loops

First off, I'll mark this as a *homework problem* I've been stuck on for a week as I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm hoping the wonderful people at SO can come to my rescue yet again (I've searched SO and other C++ sites for the past week but the solutions offered didn't correct the issue - however it is possible I may have been setting the loop incorrectly.

**The assignment:** given a text file *numbers.txt* (which contains 9,999 numbers ranging from 1 to 10,000 randomly sorted with one number missing from the consecutive list) the assignment is to use a void function in order to determine what the missing integer is.

**What I've tried:** My last attempt of this contains the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void find_number();

int main()
{
    ...

    find_number();
}

void find_number();
{
    int sum = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int num;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        sum += i;

    cout << "The sum of all the numbers between 1 and 10,000 is: " << sum << endl;

    ifstream numbers;

    numbers.open("numbers.txt");
    if (!numbers.good()) {
        return;
        cout << "Error! Unable to open file!";
    }

    if (numbers) {
        numbers >> num;

        sum1 += num;
    }


    numbers.close();
    cout << "The sum of all the numbers contained in the text file \"numbers.txt\" is: " << sum1 << endl;

cout << "By subtracting the sum of the text file from the sum of 1 to 10,000 the consecutive number missing from the text file is: " << sum - sum1 << endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: What symptom are you getting?  I notice that your code has a `return` before it can output if it's unable to open the file.  That would be good to fix.

Comment: That line is only to throw an error if the numbers file is not good. I have no problem executing the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two mistakes:

1. The return statement is executed before the diagnostic output

   ```
   if (!numbers.good()) {
       return;
       cout << "Error! Unable to open file!";
   }
   ```
2. The following lines will execute once instead of reading the whole file:

   ```
   if (numbers) {
       numbers >> num;

       sum1 += num;
   }
   ```

You can improve your code with the following suggestions:

- Extract a number and check the stream status at the same time:

  ```
  while(numbers >> num) sum1 += num;
  ```
- You don't need to close the file stream it will do it automatically in its destructor.
- You can open the file at the file stream initialization time:

  ```
  ifstream numbers("numbers.txt");
  ```

Comment: 1. Ah! I was wondering why I felt that didn't look right!
2. Yay!! Thank you so much! Your suggestion in number 2 solved the problem! I feel like such a dolt because it was such an easy loop and I see now I was trying to complicate it more than necessary! You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you are not reading the whole file

Comment: I had figured that much out when the total sum of 1 to 10,000 itself is equal to 50,005,000 and the result I was getting for the total sum of the text file was only 5,182.